# Error stacking JP2 rasters in R

Tags: r, image-processing, raster

I am trying to read and stack 12 bands of a sentinel 2 image. The images are in jp2 format. I have previously done this successfully with tiff files, but when I run the following script, I get an error:

```
sentinel2 <- list.files("path/to/folder", pattern="\\.jp2$", full.names = T) 

sentinel2_stack <- stack(sentinel2)

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  
: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

I have the raster package loaded. Any suggestions? Is it a matter of the jp2 format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already red `jp2` with the raster package so I don't think it's your problem. make sure your list of files is ok, also try reading only one raster with `raster` to see if it works.

Comment: I have tried with just one file, still doesnt work.. Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Comment: The `file does not exist` error usually happens with a stupid mistake in the path or the file name...  To validate it's not a `jp2` problem, use another software (qgis, gdal or other) to convert the file to a `tiff`, then save it in the same folder with the same name.  Try to read it, if it works, the problem is the `jp2`format, if it doesn't, the problem is more likely a typo or a authorization restriction.

Comment: I think that on windows rgdal does not include the jp2 driver.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think @RobertH is correct. I used gdaltranslate() to convert the files to tiff and continue from there.